# How I can set tokenizer for Solr field in Spring boot?

Tags: spring, solr

I have the solr document:

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "mydocument")
public class MyDocument {


    @Indexed(name = "email", type = "text_general")
    private String email;

    ...
}
```

And I want to set tokenizer for this field at `Keyword Tokenizer` beacuse I have problems when I search by email like `user@site*`.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot does not have control over these settings (it's called [Schema](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/overview-of-documents-fields-and-schema-design.html))

You've already marked the field `email`, to be named `email` and have field type of `text_general`. To change anything related to the process of indexing/searching using this filed, you need to update `schema.xml` or `managed-schema` (depends on your setup) and change fieldType definition.

Below is the standard text_general definition, you could change here `solr.StandardTokenizerFactory` to the `solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory` (however, I would recommend to rather create the new `fieldType` for this particular email field.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"> 
  <analyzer type="index"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```